# undefined reference to 'ros::init'

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am making a service, which takes two double array as input and returns another double array. Below is the sample server.cpp file-

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <kinematics/test_service.h>

bool service_callback(kinematics::test_service::Request &req, kinematics::test_service::Response &res) {
  double x1 = req.param_1[0];
  double y1 = req.param_1[1];
  double z1 = req.param_1[2];

  double x2 = req.param_2[0];
  double y2 = req.param_2[1];
  double z2 = req.param_2[2];

  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Pose {" << x1 << ", " << y1 << ", " << z1 << "}");

  res.param_3.resize(3);
  res.param_3.at(0) = x1 + x2;
  res.param_3.at(1) = y1 + y2;
  res.param_3.at(2) = z1 + z2;
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_service_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::ServiceServer service = nh.advertiseService("test_service", service_callback);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

Below is the sample client.cpp file-

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <kinematics/test_service.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "service_node_test");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::ServiceClient client =
      nh.serviceClient<kinematics::test_service>("test_service");

  std::vector<double> param_1(3);
  param_1.push_back(0.8047);
  param_1.push_back(0.1436);
  param_1.push_back(0.3308);

  std::vector<double> param_2(3);
  param_2.push_back(0.7966);
  param_2.push_back(0.1354);
  param_2.push_back(0.3337);

  kinematics::test_service service;
  service.request.param_1 = param_1;
  service.request.param_2 = param_2;

  if (client.call(service)) {
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Clinet Response " << service.response.param_3.size());
  } else {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call test_service");
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file has following content-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(service_test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS)

catkin_package(
LIBRARIES
CATKIN_DEPENDS
)

include_directories(include
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(server src/server.cpp)
add_executable(client src/client.cpp)

target_link_libraries(server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS server
ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(TARGETS client
ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY launch/
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)
```

While compiling the above code using `catkin_make`, it is throwing following error-

```
server.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'
server.cpp:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::string const&, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&)'
server.cpp:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `ros::spin()'
server.cpp:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `ros::ServiceServer::~ServiceServer()'
```

How to solve this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236149/undefined-reference-to-%27ros::init%27/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're not linking against `roscpp`, which is the library that provides those symbols.

> How to solve this error?

Link against `roscpp`. Add it to the `find_package(catkin COMPONENTS ..)` statement, and add it to your `catkin_package(.. CATKIN_DEPENDS ..)` list.

I'd also make your `CMakeLists.txt` search for your `kinematics` package, as you use that in your service server definitions.

---

Edit: this is also discussed in the [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++) - Building your nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Building_your_nodes-1) tutorial, and see the [catkin documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » C++ catkin library dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/catkin_library_dependencies.html) for how to update your `CMakeLists.txt` and package manifest.

Note also that this is not a ROS specific problem, but a standard C++ linking error, and that it has been asked many times before.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-06-06**:
Thanks . It worked.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-14**:
I am facing a similar issue.  I edited  the `CMakeLists.txt` as suggested above. But I also had to edit the package.xml to add `roscpp` as run and build dependency. Is this right way to do it or does linking `roscpp` requires me to add any additional `#include......` statements in the source file ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-14**:\

> But I also had to edit the package.xml [..]

Yes, that is what I meant with "*update your [..] package manifest*": `package.xml` is the manifest.

And, no. Provided you are not using anything not already included by `ros.h`, you don't need to add any additional `#include`s.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-15**:
Thank You.